# PHP,MYSQL while loop only displays the last record

Tags: php, mysql

my code is -

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';    
$dbuser = 'root';    
$dbpass = '';  
$dbname = 'moviefone';    
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);  
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);    

// Check connection    
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {  
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();    
}    

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_hindi") or die(mysql_error());
$info=NULL;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    $info=$row;
}

?>
```

my problem is that the loop only displays the last record from "new_hindi" table.

Comment: You mean to collect the rows into `$info`?  use `$info[] = $row;` to append onto it as an array. First initialize it as `$info = array();` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you iterate, you overwrite `$info` variable. You have to add rows to `$info` array.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';    
$dbuser = 'root';    
$dbpass = '';  
$dbname = 'moviefone';    
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);  
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);    

// Check connection    
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {  
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();    
}    

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_hindi") or die(mysql_error());
$info=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    $info[]=$row;
}

?>
```

Comment: i have tried this but now there is a undefined index.1234
WALLE
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: images in C:\wamp\www\test\website3\moviefun.php on line 114 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0008691800{main}( )..\moviefun.php:0 " width="140" height="200" class="new-img" />

Comment: I think you have to use something like `$info[0]['images']` or create another loop while using `$info` variable. I'm not sure what does `$row` contain.

Comment: yes.thanks now its working perfectly.as you say i used $info[0]['images'].

Comment: but one question? do i need to change $info[0] to $info[1],whenever i update my database??

Comment: The question is, how many rows you have in your table and, if you have more of them, why not iterate over them and show all? I'm not sure how you use data from your database.

Comment: i have more then 30 rows in my table.i want that every time i update my database it loops the latest four entry from the database.how can i do this?

Comment: If you have `id` column, to select last four rows from database you could do: `SELECT * FROM new_hindi ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4`.

Comment: well thanks i finally achieved what i wanted to do.